# How to dynamically position elements in wxPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I've not been able to find an answer in the documentation. Say I have the following:

```
import wx
from wx import *
import sys

app = wx.App() 

def quitProgram(*args):
    sys.exit()

def restart(*args):
    app.MainLoop()

xSize = 500
ySize = 300
window = wx.Frame(None, title = "My GUI", size = (xSize,ySize)) 
panel = wx.Panel(window)     

# generic label
labelLeft = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'some text', pos = (2,30))

# exit button
exit = wx.Button(panel, -1, label="Exit", pos = (1, 1), size=(-1,-1))
exit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, quitProgram)
# reset button
reset = wx.Button(panel, -1, label="Refresh", pos = (100,1), size=(-1,-1))
reset.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, restart)

window.Show(True) 

app.MainLoop()
```

How can I position the objects- buttons and labels- based on the size of the main window? I'd like the objects to reposition based on resizing the window.

Comment: Start here: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/sizers_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

The code posted is not clean wxPython code.
You must instantiate your Frame as a Class and use Sizers to automate positioning of your widgets.
A minimal code that reproduces your frame using Sizers is this:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((500, 300))
        self.bt_exit = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "exit")
        self.bt_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "refresh")
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "some text", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.SetTitle("My GUI")
        self.bt_exit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_exit)
        self.bt_refresh.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_refresh)

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_2.Add(self.bt_exit, 1, 0, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(self.bt_refresh, 1, 0, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(sizer_2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

    def on_exit(self, evt):
        self.Close()

    def on_refresh(self, evt):
        self.text_ctrl.Clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is well explained in wxPython/Phoenyx docs. Check for example [these tutorials](https://wiki.wxpython.org/SizerTutorials)